# Replace no data by zeros in datadog graphs

Tags: datadog

There does not seem to be a way to replace no data by zeros when using formulas in datadog.
I've tried fill zero but it doesn't seem to work
I would simply like my dd agent monitor to display 0 instead of no data when it is down

Answer (score 38):

how about [the "default" function](https://docs.datadoghq.com/graphing/functions/interpolation/#default)?

so `default(sum:foo.bar{hello:world} by {baz}, 0)` or some such?

Comment: Update in 2023: the "default" function is no longer documented.

Comment: Any idea why? The fill function doesn't seem to achieve the same thing, and I wanted to use a default different than zero

Answer (score 35):

The `default_zero()` function does what you're looking for. You can type it in manually, as [stephenlechner suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53345774/3141234).

There's another way I found:

1. Click "Advanced" in the bottom right:

   [image]
2. Enter `default(a, 0)` as the formula, and disable the visibility of metric `a`:

   [image]

When you save the graph and reopen, you'll see that things have been reshuffled a little, and you'll see a "default 0" section tagged onto the end of the metric's definition.

[image]

Comment: I don't have the advanced button....

Comment: As @Mark said, in the current UI I'm seeing there is no advanced button, but you *can* click the Σ button (add function) then type "default zero" in the search box to have this applied

Answer (score 10):

There is now a [default_zero()](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/functions/interpolation/#default-zero) function that can be used in Datadog by modifying through JSON directly.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to solve this by to changing the query by using zero interpolation. You can put ".fill(zero)" behind your query in the json or choose the option from the UI.
[image]

**EDIT:**

You're right, the interpolation is not working when no data is available. I had the same problem in the end. Support of Datadog said it isn't possible to show zero when there is no data for a metric. Now there is a feature request made for it. It would be nice if more people will request for this feature, so it will be prioritized.

Nonetheless I have tried to create a workaround by adding a second metric that always has data as a second query and added a formula ((b - b) + a) that negates the second query, but when there is data in the intended query it's show in the graph. This will result in a zero line when there is no data available.

**Scenario without data:**
[image: GraphWithNoData]

The only problem is that when you have a data in the intended query, it looks ugly and the zero line is gone. As you see in the following screenshot.

**Scenario with data:**
[image: GraphWithData]

**Conclusion:**
The workaround is not perfect, but it will work for some situation. For example, filling up query values with zero instead of (no data). I hope this is a bit better answer to the problem.

Comment: it seems not working with only in the doc ( https://docs.datadoghq.com/graphing/faq/interpolation-the-fill-modifier-explained/)

It say "Interpolation is not needed, when you graph 1 metric submitted from 1 source: avg:net.bytes_rcvd{host:a} (we assume this host submits this metric always with the same tag list)."